# suma de palabra en arreglo string c++

Tags: c++, array

el usuario ingresa informatica o indrustrial en un arreglo pero, quiero que sume cuantas veces se puso industrial o informatica. pero lo hice pero no me los suma la cantidad de veces de cada palabra

```
int cantidad, anio, suma_informatica=0, suma_industrial=0, mayor=0;
float promedio, suma=0, suma2=0, promedio2;
string nombre, carrera, informatica, industrial;
cout<<"ingrese cuantos alumnos son:"<<endl;
cin>>cantidad;
int arreglo[cantidad], edades[cantidad];
int anios[cantidad];
string nombres[cantidad], carreras[cantidad];

for(int i=0; i<cantidad; i++){
    suma+=edades[i];
    suma2+=anios[i];

}
for(int i=0; i<cantidad; i++){
    if(carreras[i]==informatica){
        suma_informatica++;
    }
    if(carreras[i]==industrial){
        suma_industrial++;
    }
}
if(suma_industrial==suma_informatica){
    cout<<"ambas tienen la misma ma cantidad de estudiante "<<"("<<suma_industrial<<")"<<endl;
}
else if(suma_industrial<suma_informatica){
    cout<<"la carrera que tiene mas estudiante es informatica "<<"("<<suma_informatica<<")"<<endl;
}
else if(suma_industrial>suma_informatica){
    cout<<"la carrera que tiene mas estudiante es industrial "<<"("<<suma_industrial<<")"<<endl;
}
return 0;
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

supongo que estas comenzando a programar, no logro ver donde es que estas insertando los string en el arreglo carreras.
Te recomiendo primero que luego de pedir la cantidad de estudiantes hagas un ciclo donde también pongas todos los datos que necesitas por ejemplo:

```
for(int i=0; i<cantidad; i++){
    cout<<"Insertando el estudiante: "+(cantidad+1)<<endl;
    cout<<"Nombre:"<<endl;
    cin>>nombres[cantidad];
    cout<<"Edad:"<<endl;
    cin>>edades[cantidad];    
    cout<<"Carrera:"<<endl;
    cin>>carreras[cantidad];
    cout<<"Anio:"<<endl;
    cin>>anios[cantidad]   
}
```

Con este cambio y cambiando tambien en el IF que comprueba las carreras, en vez de usar la variable *informatica* que no le has asignado valor aún utilizar simplemente un string "informatica", lo mismo para industrial.

También te sugiero que utilices un arreglo para las opciones de las carreras y utilizas su indice para que el usuario seleccione, entonces en vez de recibir un string recibes un entero por ejemplo, 
0. informatica
1. industrial

o validar las opciones sustituyendo este fragmento

```
cout<<"Carrera:"<<endl;
cin>>carreras[cantidad];
```

por este otro (que es una solucion un poco cutre pero bueno)

```
do{
    cout<<"Carrera:"<<endl;
    cin>>carreras[cantidad];
    if(carreras[cantidad] != "informatica" && carreras[cantidad] != "industrial")
        cout<<"incorrecto, debe ser informatica o industrial"<<endl;
}
while(carreras[cantidad] != "informatica" && carreras[cantidad] != "industrial")
```

Espero que sea de ayuda, saludos.

PD: te recomiendo tambien investigar las estructuras y las clases en c++ que te pueden ayudar para conformar un objeto de Estudiante, pero quiza en estos momentos no has visto esas cosas todavía, suerte.

Comment: muchas gracias te pasaste :)

Comment: por nada, un gusto ayudar.